# Ubuntu 18.04 takes 3-4 hours to show up the lock screen after re-start or start

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, startup, crash

In error it shows

> nautilus crashed with SIGSEGV

```
ProblemType: Crash
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 18.04
Package: nautilus 1:3.26.0-0ubuntu1
```